# Obtaining the Eclipse text font

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

How do I get a Font object representing the font set as the "Text Font" in the Eclipse Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts? I'm implementing a table-view where one of the columns is supposed to contained fixed-width text.

Comment: So, you're writing an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be easier than expected. The font is obtained like this:

```
    font = JFaceResources.getTextFont();
```

There are similar methods for dialog and banner fonts.